# run function multiple times

Tags: python

i have a list:

```
my_list[8000,8001,8002]
```

function:

```
def print_function(number):
   print(number)
```

What do i want?

I want to run the function multiple times, in this example 3 times with the numbers from the list.
So the outcome has to be:

```
8000
8001
8002
```

In other words i want to pass the items from the list to the function and run the function as many times as there are items in the list.
I am very new to python, so excuse me if its a simple question.

Comment: This question is off-topic

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop:

```
for i in my_list:
     print_function(i)
```